# Creating an array of checkboxes tied to a single list with tkinter?

Tags: python, list, tkinter, checkbox

I'm trying to make a window that will provide a grid of checkboxes that looks like this: [grid of checkboxes 10x10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTQE7.png)

I've got the following code to create it:

```
checks = Tk()
    checks.title("Check Grid")
    value = []
    z = 1
    for x in range(1,11): # Row
        for y in range(1,11): # Column
            value.append('')
            box = Checkbutton(checks, text = z, variable = value[(z)-1])
            box.grid(row = x, column = y, sticky = S)
            z += 1
    #exit button
    def exit():
        print(value)
        checks.destroy()
    Label = Button(checks, text = 'Exit',command = exit).grid(row = 11)
    checks.mainloop()

    return value`
```

with this: `box = Checkbutton(checks, text = z, variable = value[(x*y)-1])` I'm trying to assign the checkbox value to the z value of the `value` list. This doesn't appear to be working, any ideas?

**question:**
How do I make a grid of checkboxes, using tkinter, that send their values to their list index of a single list?

Comment: The variable must be a tkinter variable (`StringVar` usually). In your case (`value.append("")`) it is a normal python string. Change that line to `value.append(StringVar())`

Comment: Alright, I did that, but I'm getting the same result. I've even made a new list that iterates through the `value` list and appends value[x].get()

Answer (score 0):

The target of the `variable` option needs to be a tkinter variable, and you need to make sure to keep a reference to those variables (ie: they can't be local variables)

```
values = []
for x in range(1,11): # Row
    for y in range(1,11): # Column
        var = IntVar(value=0)
        values.append(var)
        box = Checkbutton(checks, text=z, variable=var)
        ...
...
def exit():
    data = [value.get() for value in values]
    print(data)
    checks.destroy()
```

Comment: Please pass in the `master` keyword argument when creating the `IntVar` (add `master=checks` to `var = IntVar(value=0)`).

Comment: @TheLizzard: no, it's not necessary in this example.

Comment: Putting `master=checks` in `var = IntVar(value=0)` is the same as having the `checks` in `box = Checkbutton(checks, )`. For consistency I would either never pass the `master` parameter or always pass the `master` parameter. We can agree that we can't leave it out of the `Checkbutton` even though it wouldn't change the way the program looks/behaves

Comment: @TheLizzard: _"Putting master=checks in var = IntVar(value=0) is the same as having the checks in box = Checkbutton(checks, )"_ - actually, no, it's not. Widgets live in a hierarchy, and the first argument establishes the hierarchy. The `master` argument for a variable isn't to establish a hierarchy, it's to define which interpreter the variable belongs to. A well-designed tkinter app will only have a single interpreter so there's no need to disambiguate.

Comment: *"A well-designed tkinter app will only have a single interpreter"* - I disagree. The first argument of `IntVar`/`Checkbutton`/`Button`/... is the `master` argument. So you can actually use `var = IntVar(checks, value=0)`. The only difference between `IntVar` and `Checkbutton` is that `Checkbutton` can be shown on the screen (according to my view of how tcl works). Therefore, passing the first argument for `Checkbutton` is the same as passing the first argument (the `master` argument) for `IntVar`.

Comment: @TheLizzard: _"The only difference between IntVar and Checkbutton is that Checkbutton can be shown on the screen "_ - that is very far from the truth. Checkbuttons and IntVars are fundamentally very different things. _"Therefore, passing the first argument for Checkbutton is the same as passing the first argument (the master argument) for IntVar"_ - that is also simply not true. Variables don't live in a hierarchy. Although you can pass any widget in as the master to a variable, the only think tkinter uses is the root window that owns the widget.

Comment: Ok just found out that we `Variable` class doesn't keep the `master` but keeps the `master._root` - I was wrong. But I still think that it is best practise to pass it in because it doesn't take that much effort and if you need to use another instance of `Tk()`, it would save debugging time.